I'm struggling to add a p5.js sketch to my Astro website
I'm developing my personal website with Astro. Parts of my website require running p5.js sketches. I have added <script> tags for both p5.js and my sketch, but when I run the page, it's as if p5.js isn't running. There is no canvas added to the DOM, nor are there any errors in the console.
I have added a console.log to my sketch, so I can confirm that my sketch code is running.
If I download p5.js locally, place it in the /Public folder and import it with <script is:inline src="/p5.js"></script> then I can verify that it also does run with a console.log. Alternatively, if I import p5.js from the CDN, then I can see from the network logs that the script is being downloaded without issue.
I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot this problem. Any help would be appreciated!
Minimal Example
Here's an Astro page (put in the pages folder) which illustrates my problem:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>min p5js with astro example</title>

        <!-- Import p5.js. First way is directly from the downloaded source in /public. SEcond way is from the CDN -->
        <!-- <script is:inline src="/p5.js"></script> -->
        <script is:inline src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>


        <script>
            console.log("Running script...")
            function setup() {
                createCanvas(400, 400);
                background(0);
            }

            function draw() {
                fill(255);
                ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

So far I've tried

Importing p5.js from both the CDK and downloading locally.
Importing the minimum compressed version, but made no difference (unsuprisingly).
Writing the sketch code directly in the <script> tags.
Writing the sketch code in its own js file and importing it with <script>import '../scripts/mySketch.js'</script>.
Adding console.logs to confirm that the javascript is being run (which it is).


The [mcve] needs to be in the question itself. Links can disappear over time, making the question less useful to future visitors.

Have you tried doing npm install p5 and then putting something like this in <script> tag without is:inline? That would be the "modern" way. Alternatively, you have to use is:inline in all the script tags. See https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/

Aha! Thanks @mb21, adding is:inline to all the scripts interacting with p5.js was the way. I realise it's old fashioned and is skipping the optimisation process given by Astro, but given I have many sketches to migrate onto this new site, it is not feasible to refactor them all with the modern approach.
Thanks for your help. I encourage you to post it as an answer to I can mark it as the solution! If you can explain technically why adding is:inline to the other scripts  solves the problem, I'd be grateful :)

Is it because if my sketch code is not inline while the p5 library is, then when the sketch code compiles the compiler doesn't have a view of the library. So the compiler sees setup and draw as unused functions, and eliminates them for the sake of optimisation?

@PeterMarsh thanks, I added it as an answer. Yes, you can see in the browser's dev tools how the Astro-processed output looks like. But yes, I would expect it to optimize unused functions completely away.

You either do the "modern" way: npm install p5 and then putting something like this in  tag without is:inline:
<script>
import p5 from 'p5'
new p5(mySketch, document.getElementById('sketch'))
</script>

The above treats the code as a module (meaning local variables are not assigned to window, etc.) and runs it through Astro's bundler and minimizer (using vite under the hood).
Alternatively, you have to use is:inline in all the script tags. This prevents Astro from processing the script:
<script is:inline src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script is:inline>
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
  }
  function draw() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
  }
</script>

Which is assigning the two functions to window.setup and window.draw respectively.

Thank you so much for the further explanation!
